# vb.net 2008 express: Two textboxes in a custom control

Tags: vb.net, textbox, custom-controls

I'm making a custom control in VB.net 2008 Express.  Without getting into the details, I am able to duplicate the issue as follows:

Make a blank custom control.  Stick two textboxes on it.  Don't add any code.

Run it and click the second textbox. (Don't click the first.)  The text cursor appears of course.

Now Type... Although the text cursor moves within the second textbox, the text you type appears in the first textbox, not the second one.

I have found that this issue depends on the tab order of the controls.  Whichever textbox is first in the tab order gets text typed in the other.

I have also found that if you press [Tab] to set focus on either textbox, the problem goes away.

QUESTIONS:

1) Is this a known bug in .net?  (Specifically 2008 Express)

2) Will this phenomenon carry over when the custom control is brought into a larger project?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean an `UserControl` when you say custom control?

Comment: I followed the steps you mentioned above and put the control into the default form created when making a windows application and ran it. The issue didn't occur for me in Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

Comment: Yes I meant UserControl.  It sounds like you brought the usercontrol into a "blank" project... Did you try duplicating issue in the UserControl test container?  That's where I see it happening.  Frankly I'll know soon enough whether this carries over into a full project, so it's not a question I really had to ask.  But this issue was infuriating for a while, as I was blaming my own code... Only once I trimmed it down to bare bones did I discover... it's probably not my fault.  Meanwhile, I'm checking for updates.

Comment: Accurate to +/- 1%, nobody ever uses the UC Test Container.  It is just easier to drop it on a form and run that, much easier to debug.  This bug was probably fixed a while ago, VS2013 doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the steps above and was able to reproduce it when I started with a `Windows Form Control Library` and ran it inside the `UserControl TestContainer`. I test this in Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

However, when I placed the user control inside a form in a separate `Windows Forms Application` project, the issue did not occur. So I'd think it's safe to say that this won't be an issue when the user control is used in another project.

Comment: Thanks.  Contrary to Hans' advice I'm still going to use the test container because I like being able to manipulate the properties of my control while it's running, but I've gained an appreciation for debugging a control while it's in a real project.

Comment: I had no idea that there was a test container until today. Thanks for introducing me to it ;)